# Can not access ids of .kv file from main.py file in kivy

Tags: android, class, python-2.7, kivy

I have main.py as below :

I have two clss and one of them is `pscan` which basically do a process

and then do another process using loops

but i can not access any attributes to another class using pscan class

it always gives me error like

```
class pscan has no attributes 'pb'
```

```html
from kivy.app import App
import socket, sys, threading, os, time
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class pscan(threading.Thread):
    
    def __init__(self,ip, port):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port

    def run(self):
        self.ids["pb"].value=self.ids["pb"].value+1    #Increasing progress bar
#Which is not working on this level it give me erro


        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.settimeout(4)
            s.connect((socket.gethostbyname(self.ip), int(self.port)))
            print "\n[+] OPEN:",self.ip, self.port
            s.close()
        except:
            print "\n[!] CLOSE:",self.ip, self.port

  


class ExampleRoot(BoxLayout):
    sport = 1
    target = 'www.google.com'
    eport= 100

    def final(self,*args):
        self.ids["pb"].max=int(self.eport)   ##defining size of progress bar
        while self.sport <= self.eport:
            work = pscan(self.target, self.sport) 
            work.start()            
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.sport = self.sport + 1


class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ExampleRoot()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ExampleApp().run()
```

Here is my example.kv file :

```html
<Exampleroot>
  
  BoxLayout:
  
    Button:
      text:"PRESS ME TO RUN PSCAN CLASS"
      on_press:root.final()
  
    ProgressBar:     ### I want this increasing using main.py when each port get scan  using pscan class
      id:pb
      max:0
      value:0
```

any solution guys ??

Comment: Can you post the full error/traceback?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `self.ids["pb"]` from the `pscan` class. But just like the error says, the `pscan` class doesn't have an attribute called `pb`. You defined the widget with the id 'pb' in the `ExampleRoot` class in the .kv file.

I am a bit confused, because you never explicitly call the `pscan` classes `run()` method(Did you mean to override the `start` method?). However, if you want the progress bars value to be incremented each time you start a new thread, you could do that inside the while loop in `ExampleRoot`, and shouldn't receive that particular error anymore, as the widget with id 'pb' exists inside of `ExampleRoot`.

```
while self.sport <= self.eport:
    work = pscan(self.target, self.sport) 
    work.start()
    self.ids.pb.value += 1    # <<< try it here        
    time.sleep(0.1)
    self.sport = self.sport + 1
```